# how to delete a range of partitions in DolphinDB database

Tags: delete-row, partition, dolphindb

I have a composite partitions in DolphinDB. How do I delete a range of partitions without specifying each individual partition? For example, for a

```
dbDate = database(, VALUE, 2017.08.07..2017.08.11)
dbID = database(, RANGE, 0 50 100 150 200 250 300)
db = database("dfs://compoDB", COMPO, [dbDate, dbID])
```

How do I delete partitions from 50 to 300? I tried the following:

```
dropPartition(db,[,[50,250]]);
```

Looks like only the partitions [50, 100) and [250, 300) are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use pair to represent a range. Please try the code below.

```
dropPartition(db,[,50:250])
```